# Integer-sided triangles with equal perimeters and equal areas

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry, triangles, diophantine-equations, integers

What is a way to find the side-lengths of non-congruent triangles whose perimeters are equal, and whose areas are equal?

(I have posted an answer below. This shows how answers to my question are related to answers to a question posted elsewhere on math.SE.)

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this a duplicate? (I did check and found none.)

Answer (score 1):

Find some sets of three integers $\{x_i, y_i, z_i\}$, each with sum equal to $s$ and product equal to $p$, as shown, for example, in [S. Dolan's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3534245). Then the side-lengths of the $i$th triangle are $\{a_i, b_i, c_i\}=\{s-x_i, s-y_i, s-z_i\}$. The triangles have semi-perimeter $s$ and area $\Delta=\sqrt{sp}$. As a bonus, seeing as a triangle's inradius is $r=\Delta/s$, the triangles have equal inradii, too.

If you select only sets where $sp$ is a square, then the area will be an integer and the triangles will be Heronian.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the triangles,

$(a,a,2b)=(p^2+4q),(p^2+4q),(8q)$

$(d,d,2f)=(4p+q^2)(4p+q^2),(8p)$

Since perimeter's are equal we get the condition,

$(p+q)=8$  ----(1)

Using the value $p=(8-q)$ we also have the semi perimeter,

$s=p^2-8p+64$

We have the area formula for triangle $(a,b,c)$,

$A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$

So we get,

$(s-a)=4(8-p)$

$(s-2b)=p^2$

$(s-d)=(4p)$

$(s-2f)=(8-p)^2$

Hence common Area is,

$A^2=(p^2-8p+64)(4)^2(p)^2(8-p)^2$  ----(2)

To make the (RHS) of (2) a square the equations (1) & (2)

are both satisfied at $(p,q)=(3,5)$

Hence we have two triangles:

$(a,a,2b)=(29,29,40)$ &

$(d,d,2f)=(37,37,24)$

their, perimeter=$98$ & area=$420$

Below is the link to paper written by Andrew Bremner &

also link to article by Seiji Tomita

https://www.emis.de//journals/AMI/2006/ami2006-bremner.pdf

http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph312e.html